# json (has multiple value) parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
```

this is a log from above code.

```
"{\"result\":{\"normal\":0.002,\"soft\":0.776,\"adult\":0.222}}"
```

this is a result of json String but I can't how to parsing normal, soft, adult value

Comment: It looks like you are trying to turn something that is already a string into a string.  (Hence the `\"` stuff.  I think you really want `JSON.parse`

Comment: It's suggested to search before post a new thread, as you can imagine this is a very common question so there should be some one who asked the same before, like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

To parse the JSON string just use indexing on the key's value. Something like this would help you retrieve the value of normal in the JSON object:

```
console.log(body['result']['normal']);
```

Read up more about the JSON object and how to handle them: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: No worries but as suggested in the comments, try searching for the question before asking :)